# Does "webpack-dev-server"' compile my files to disk?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

In webpack's [getting started](https://webpack.github.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started/) page, under the section about `webpack-dev-server` it mentions -

> The dev server uses webpack’s watch mode. It also prevents webpack
>   from emitting the resulting files to disk. Instead it keeps and serves
>   the resulting files from memory.

Does this mean that the bundled file `webpack-dev-server` compiles is only kept in memory, and I have to also leave `webpack --watch` running in the background along with the dev-server process to actually save the compiled file to my hard drive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`webpack-dev-server` apparently does not compile your code to disk, but rather keeps it in memory. This means you need to either manually compile your changes, or run `webpack --watch` in the background as you make changes if you want the changes reflected in your compiled file. I learned the [hard way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278696/polymer-web-app-is-not-rendering-any-of-the-components).

After digging a little deeper into the webpack-dev-server [docs](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html):

> This modified bundle is served from memory at the relative path
>   specified in publicPath (see API). It will not be written to your
>   configured output directory. Where a bundle already exists at the same
>   URL path, the bundle in memory takes precedence (by default).

Comment: Unfortunately for my application. The files are being loaded directly from the disk even though the changes are being marked on memory with [tag:webpack-dev-middleware]. SO, I had to add writeToDisk: true . This way the changes are market on disk and finally I am able to see it on the browser. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62957820/bundle-created-by-webpack-does-not-reflect-changes-on-the-browser-after-successf

Answer (score 1):

in [webpack 5](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverdevmiddleware), you can set `devServer.devMiddleware.writeToDisk` to true. This will compile the files to disk on your target location.

```
    devServer: {
        port: port,
        static: {
            directory: path.resolve(__dirname,'./dist'),
        },
        devMiddleware: {
            index: "[name].html",
            writeToDisk: true
        },
        open:true,
        // default fall back if browser endpoints do not exist.
        historyApiFallback: {
            index: 'dashboard.html'
        }
    },
```